# Resque command works from terminal but not via bluepill

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque, bluepill

I am trying to get bluepill to monitor my resque workers.

If i run this command from my rails root as root user it starts up resque worker ok.

```
cd /var/www/domain.com/current; RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
```

but when i try to run it using bluepill it just keeps trying to start it and doesnt give me an error.

Here is my bluepill log showing it trying....!

```
W, [2011-07-12T22:58:21.640467 #19267]  WARN -- : [domain.com:resque] Executing start command: cd /var/www/domain.com/current; RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
I, [2011-07-12T22:58:21.754392 #19267]  INFO -- : [domain.com:resque] Going from down => starting

I, [2011-07-12T22:59:21.334300 #19267]  INFO -- : [domain.com:resque] Going from starting => down
W, [2011-07-12T22:59:22.339873 #19267]  WARN -- : [domain.com:resque] Executing start command: cd /var/www/domain.com/current; RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
I, [2011-07-12T22:59:22.479740 #19267]  INFO -- : [domain.com:resque] Going from down => starting
```

it keeps doing this over and over.

here is my .pill file process

```
app.process("resque") do |process|
  process.start_command = "cd #{RAILS_ROOT}; RAILS_ENV=#{RAILS_ENV} QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work"
  process.daemonize = true

  process.start_grace_time = 10.seconds
  process.stop_grace_time = 10.seconds
  process.restart_grace_time = 10.seconds
end
```

I have tried to extend the start grace time for if its not loading in the required time but not making a difference.

Please can anyone help with this ?

thanks in advance
Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not adapted to use bundle exec (a little old) but can be edited easily.

This is my production environment Bluepill AudioBox.fm config, battle tested, happy to share.

```
ENVIRONMENT = 'production'
RAILS_ROOT  = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || "/var/www/myapp/current"

Bluepill.application("myapp", :log_file => "/var/log/bluepill.log") do |app|
  app.uid = "ubuntu"
  app.gid = "ubuntu"

  4.times do |i|
    app.process("uploaders-#{i}") do |process|
      process.working_dir = RAILS_ROOT
      process.group = "resque"
      queues = "amazon_upload"
      process.start_command = "/usr/bin/env VERBOSE=true RAILS_ENV=#{ENVIRONMENT} QUEUE=#{queues} rake resque:work --trace"
      process.stop_command = <<-EOF
      kill -QUIT {{PID}}
      sleep_count=0
      while [ -e /proc/{{PID}} ]; do
        sleep 1
        let "sleep_count+=1"
        if [ $sleep_count -eq 60 ]; then
          kill -TERM {{PID}}
        fi
        if [ $sleep_count -ge 70 ]; then
          kill -KILL {{PID}}
        fi
      done
      EOF

      process.stdout = process.stderr = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/resque.log"
      process.pid_file      = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/pids/resque-uploader-#{i}.pid"
      process.daemonize     = true
      process.start_grace_time = 5.seconds
      process.stop_grace_time = 75.seconds
      process.restart_grace_time = 80.seconds

      process.checks :mem_usage, :below => 350.megabytes, :every => 1.minute, :times => 3
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You should really look into using resque-pool, it greatly simplifies things and gives you better control of your queues, if you have a lot of them processing different tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Did @kain's answer solve your problem?  I have something very similar just started happening, see [bluepill not detecting that processes have, in fact, started successfully, and so creates new ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371594/bluepill-not-detecting-that-processes-have-in-fact-started-successfully-and-s)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of bluepill you were on, but I just fixed a bug which manifested itself in exactly that behavior.  [Pull request submitted](https://github.com/arya/bluepill/pull/141).

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this kind of thing with capistrano + resque...

in ssh -> sudo service redis start, starts

through capistrano -> sudo service redis start, says command worked but no process...