# bluepill not detecting that processes have, in fact, started successfully, and so creates new ones

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, resque, chef-infra, bluepill

I have one (EC2) Ubuntu server where `bluepill` is working just fine to start and monitoring `resque` processes (and it has done so on other nodes in the past).

I'm setting up a new node, and for some reason on this node `bluepill` does not recognize that the processes have started and are running, and so keeps creating new ones.  I'm a little baffled by what's causing this.  The 2 nodes are almost identical; they're both EC2 servers provisioned by the same `chef` scripts.  It is true that the one not working is 'production' and the other 'staging', but there's almost no difference due to that.

Any thoughts or suggestions before I fork the github project and start inserting more monitoring, to try and figure out what's going on?  There's been discussion on this list in the past about troubles w/ `bluepill` and `resque`, but as I said this is working fine on my staging server, and has worked fine on earlier production servers (although I will note that this new production server is ruby 1.9.3 (vs 1.9.2) and rails 3.2 (vs. 3.1)).

Here's my `.pill` file (or more specifically, my `chef` cookbook's template file):

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "<%= node.chef_environment %>"
ENV["QUEUE"] = "*"

Bluepill.application("zmx_app") do |app|
  app.working_dir = "/srv/zmx/current"
  app.uid = "root"
  app.gid = "root"
  2.times do |i|
    app.process("resque-#{i}") do |process|
      process.group = "resque"
      process.start_command = "rake resque:work"
      process.pid_file = "/srv/zmx/current/tmp/pids/resque_workers-#{i}.pid"
      process.stop_command = "kill -QUIT {{PID}}"
      process.daemonize = true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in bluepill, which I have forked, fixed, and [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/arya/bluepill/pull/141).

And I'm not sure why I didn't realize that there was, in fact, a difference between my two environments: staging/old prod was on bluepill 0.0.55, my new production environment on 0.0.58.